# Why is $C(X)$ not locally compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Problem: Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space without isolated point. and $C(X)$ be the vector space of real-valued continuous functions on $X$. Prove that $C(X)$ is not locally compact under uniform topology(metric topology induced by uniform metric).

Given solution: We know that $X$ is uncountable. Now construct $\{x_0, x_1,...\}$ and $\{V_0 ,V_1 ,...\}$ where $V_i $'s are open subsets of $X$, satisfying the three conditions:

(i)$V_0 = X, x_0 \in V_0$.

(ii)$\bar{V}_{n+1} \subset V_n \backslash \{x_n\}$ for all nonnegative integer $n$. This construction of $V_{n+1}$ is possible since $X$ is normal.

(iii)$x_{n+1} \in V_{n+1}$

Then, by Urysohn's lemma, there is a continuous function $f_n$ satisfing $f_n(x_n )=1$ and $f_n(x)=0$ for all $x\in X \backslash V_n$ for every $n$.

Note that $||f_n||=1$ and $||f_m-f_n||=1$ whenever $m\neq n$.

Now let $K$ be a compact subset of $C(X)$. We need to prove that $K$ cannot have an interior point.

Suppose $K$ has an interior point, then there exist $g \in C(X)$ and $r>0$ such that $B(g,r) \subset K$.

The given solution claims that the open cover $\mathcal B = \{B(g+rf_i/2,r/2):i=0,1,2,...\}\cup \{X-\{f_0,f_1,...\}\}$ covers $K$, but I can't figure out why.

Also, the solution claims that any finite subcover of $\mathcal B$ cannot cover $K$, which is a contradiction. However, I cannot understand why not.

Does anyone have any ideas to explain? Or does the given solution have an error?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Oh thanks I just revised the question:)

Comment: Looks like a mistake. Not $X - \{ f_0, f_1,\dotsc\}$ but $X - \bigl\{ g + \frac{r}{2}f_0, g + \frac{r}{2}f_1,\dotsc\bigr\}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh then everything makes sense. Thanks:)

Comment: Alternative proof: the $f_n$ show that $C(X)$ is an infinite dimensional topological vector space. These are never locally compact.